# multi-layered web application user registration options

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4, user-registration

Newbie here.

I've seen quite a few examples where IdentityServer is used for user authentication and authorization, but that assumes I've a way to register users.

I'm planning an Angular front-end and an ASP.net Core C# application using Clean Architecture principles. I want to register the users and then have IdentityServer4 manage the authentication and authorization for my application.

What technical options do I've to register my users?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should make that an answer @Dennis1679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, IdentityServer plugs into the asp NET Core Identity, and supports local user accounts but also social accounts, all you need is a database for Core Identity to store the user data and you're good to go.

And here's a tip if you have questions like this again, remember this first:
Microsoft does an awesome job documenting anything .NET Core related, there is so much good hands-on information out there, that should be your first go-to. The documentation on identity & identity server you can [find here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).